# Appimage vs. Flatpak vs Snap apps number

Tags: snap, flatpak, appimage

I was wondering which one of those package managers contain the biggest selection of apps.

Honestly speaking this fragmentation is confusing and frustrating. Instead of uniting behind one package manager and then create it really good now we have three, fighting between each other.

I am personally leaning towards Appimage, but the selection of apps available seems more limited.

According to the tags usage, there were 34 questions tagged with `flatpak`, 49 with `snap` and 0 with `appimage`, even though this one is the oldest one. So I guess `snap` should be the most popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who works on Snapcraft, I can tell you as developers we're not 'fighting' with eachother. That's entirely user-developed human-nature tribalism at work. The fact is each has advantages over the others, and there isn't a one-size fits all.

To answer your question about popularity..

At the time of writing there are [733](https://ahayzen.com/direct/flathub.html#appcount) flatpaks in flathub. Around [4442](https://snapstats.org/) snaps in the Snap Store. There's [969](https://appimage.github.io/apps/) AppImages listed on AppImage Hub.

There may be more flatpaks in external self-hosted repositories, so this number may not fully represent the number of flatpaks available. However, flathub is the more popular way to distribute flatpaks. There may also be flatpaks lurking in download folders which users can side-load.

The number of snaps may not be accurate either because the data only covers the public snap store. Canonical run a private snap store offering for device manufacturers. So there are more snaps there. As with flatpak there are snaps available to download on various download pages, but this is less common, because the snap developers encourage distribution via the Snap Store.

Appimages are designed to be self hosted, so there's not a central 'store' which provides numbers. There are a ton of appimages which only reside on the download page of a product, or in a github repository release area.